# What does "blood drains from stomach"mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idioms

what is the meaning of "blood drains from stomach"? Elisa is shocked, so I suppose it's the same like "stomach churns​/​lurches​/​tightens", but is it really so?

> And then ... next thing I was in a police
> station, answering questions. I told them how to contact
> Papa and he came to fetch me.’
> **Blood drains from Elissa’s stomach**. ‘You were in a police
> station?’
> Uh-huh.’
> ‘What did you say?’
> ‘Well . . . I told them about the crow Papa fixed.’
> Her mouth falls open. ‘Did you tell them about me, Elijah?

Sam Lloyd "Memory Wood"

Comment: You seem to be correct.  It's a really weird way to go about saying that, though.

Comment: It’s a mash up of two more usual ways to express alarm: “[blood draining from someone’s face](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/the-blood-drains-from-someone-s-face)” and “[someone’s stomach twists/lurches](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/someone-s-stomach-churns-lurches-tightens?q=someone%E2%80%99s+stomach+churns%2Flurches%2Ftightens)”.

Comment: I suppose biologically there's some truth to the usage (doubtless one side effect of alarm-induced adrenaline flooding the body would be to divert resources / blood supply from "non-urgent" processes like *digestion*, in preparation for fight or flight). But @ColleenV is right - it's a "mash-up". Some people might like it (as "arresting, fresh" imagery), but some might think it's a bit silly (or even "incompetent", if we didn't know it came from a competent native speaker).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I chalk turns of phrase like that up to inexperienced writers or writers churning out a lot of books where the story is more important to them than the language.

Comment: @ColleenV: I don't (yet) know anything about the author, but after I click "Add comment" here I'll probably google him. At the moment, my feeling is that if the first time I encountered this particular mash-up was in a *conversational* context, I'd probably have thought it was "witty" (unless the speaker was obviously not very fluent). In a *written* context, though, I'm inclined to think it's not really "clever" enough nor "poetic" enough to justify using - but that's just my opinion, which not everyone would share.

Comment: ...apparently, *[Sam Lloyd's debut thriller](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/The_Rising_Tide.html?id=5CmazgEACAAJ&source=kp_author_description&redir_esc=y), **The Memory Wood**, was published to **huge critical acclaim** in 2020. His second thriller, **The Rising Tide**, will be published in May 2022.* I guess that means he's a competent writer!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Competent but inexperienced. I think that once a writer achieves some level of success, they get access to better editors that help them refine their writing and avoid distracting readers with weird mangling of set expressions.

Comment: @ColleenV: Once you get access to better editors, ***the world is your whelk**!* I must have said that dozens if not hundreds of times over a lifetime of making feeble attempts to be witty, but only just now while writing this comment have I attempted to see if that one has been used by others. [Apparently not!](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+world+is+your+whelk%22)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't think it helps that the other meaning of "whelk" is "pustule" :) I wonder if that etymology was a commentary on the dining experience.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I don't remember if it was me or one of my family who first came out with that particular "facetious malapropism" - but it was in the context of an amusing dining experience some decades ago. Nibbles and snacks were put on our pub garden table, and there was just one single whelk sitting in a bowl of much smaller (shelled) winkles. Nobody fancied the whelk, so it just sat there alone when its younger brethren had all been chomped up. The only volunteer to finish it off was my by-then-already-toothless father, who valiantly "gummed" it for some time before giving up! :)